# can't get multistep ajax webform work with computed field

Tags: webforms, 9

When ever I use multistep webform with computed field and try to enter data in second page, webform redirect me to first page with validation error.
Source code of my webform,

```
    page_1:
      '#type': wizard_page
      '#title': 'Page 1'
      name:
        '#type': textfield
        '#title': Name
        '#required': true
    page_2:
      '#type': wizard_page
      '#title': 'Test Page'
      test_table:
        '#type': webform_table
        '#title': Test
        '#title_display': none
        test_length:
          '#type': table_row
          '#title': Length
          test_length_material:
            '#type': number
            '#title': 'test Length Current'
            '#title_display': none
            '#placeholder': '0'
          test_length_material_1:
            '#type': computed_twig
            '#title': 'test Length Comp'
            '#template': '{{( data.test_length_material )}}'
            '#store': true
            '#ajax': true
            '#title_display': none
        test_width:
          '#type': table_row
          '#title': Width
          test_width_material:
            '#type': number
            '#title': 'test Width Current'
            '#title_display': none
            '#placeholder': '0'
          test_width_material_1:
            '#type': computed_twig
            '#title': 'test Width Material 1'
            '#template': '{{( data.test_width_material )}}'
            '#store': true
            '#ajax': true
            '#title_display': none
        test_thickness:
          '#type': table_row
          '#title': Thickness
          test_thickness_material:
            '#type': number
            '#title': 'test Thickness Current'
            '#title_display': none
            '#placeholder': '0'
          test_thickness_material_1:
            '#type': number
            '#title': 'test Thickness Material 1'
            '#placeholder': '0'
            '#title_display': none
        test_volume:
          '#type': table_row
          '#title': volume
          test_volume_computed:
            '#type': computed_twig
            '#title': 'test Volume Material'
            '#template': '{% if data.test_length_material|length and data.test_width_material|length and data.test_thickness_material|length %} {{ (( data.test_length_material * data.test_width_material * data.test_thickness_material ) / 1000000) }}{% endif %}'
            '#ajax': true
            '#title_display': none
          test_volume_computed_1:
            '#type': computed_twig
            '#title': 'test Volume Material 1'
            '#template': '{% if data.test_length_material|length and data.test_width_material|length and data.test_thickness_material_1|length %} {{ (( data.test_length_material * data.test_width_material * data.test_thickness_material_1 ) / 1000000) }}{% endif %}'
            '#ajax': true
            '#title_display': none
```

Webform version is 6.1.3. Also ajax setting is set true for above webform.
For more clarity, I have configure my webform in simplytest.me. [Click Here](https://master-i3kyji1v3zl5xjvbf566lc8sjkufnw4b.tugboatqa.com/form/cal). Anyone have any idea why it is not working ?

Comment: Could you please limit the code sample to the smallest possible one that exhibits the bug?

Comment: @cilefen, the bug come at any time. Means as soon as I move to next page or while adding data for next page element. I already minimize my sample code as much as possible.

Comment: This requires four computed fields to reproduce then? Are fields like `test_length_label` crucial to reproducing the bug?

Comment: @cilefen Thanks. I got your point. I have updated the code as per your comment. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact validation error? Is anything logged by Drupal?

Comment: Name field is required and name field is highlighted as required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145108/discussion-between-sudha-and-cilefen).